# GMOCK Argument Verification

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have a class, with member array of type int

```
// Class Defenition
class Foo {
     int array[5];
     // ... Other Memebers
}
```

Have another class with member function that has a parameter of type Foo*

```
class SerialTXInterface {
 public:
    virtual bool print_foo(Foo* strPtr) = 0;
    // ... Other Members
};
```

Mock for the above method:

```
MOCK_METHOD1(print_str_s, bool(Array_s<char>* strPtr));
```

The SerialTX interface

```
SerialTXInterface* STX = &SerialTXObject;
```

The Foo object

```
Foo FooObj;
```

The function call

```
STX.print_foo(&FooOjb)
```

How can I verify that the Foo member array[5] == {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

Comment: There are [_matchers_](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Using_Matchers), and [_custom matchers_](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CheatSheet#Defining_Matchers)?

Comment: But how do you match a pointee of a pointee? Since argument is the pointer of a class the the array is the pointer.

Comment: Arrays aren't pointers.

Comment: The only thing I can find is to use Invoke() but that requires an additional function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me (if I make `Foo::array` public)

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

using namespace testing;

class Foo {
public:
    int array[5];
    // ... Other Memebers
};

class SerialTXInterface {
public:
    virtual bool print_foo(Foo* strPtr) = 0;
    // ... Other Members
};

class SerialTXMock {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(print_foo, bool(Foo* strPtr));
};

TEST(STXUser, Sends12345)
{
    SerialTXMock STXM;
    EXPECT_CALL(STXM, print_foo(Pointee(Field(&Foo::array,ElementsAre(1,2,3,4,    5)))));
    Foo testfoo = {{1,2,3,4,5}};
    STXM.print_foo(&testfoo);
}
```